# add on with google app domain

Tags: google-apps, add-on

I received a requirement and I'm totally lost, I hope some1 can light me.

This is my scenario:

The client bought a domain to google app, let's assume abc.com, I thought he also received a server space but he didn't apparently he only has the domain for mail etc (I don't get exactly how google apps works).

Now, this client needs a website (wordpress based) in that domain, so basically my boss will store the page on his server (JustHost) and with an add on, will make the domain point to that direction. So at end of the day people will be able to reach abc.com and the link will remain as it is.

I went into the google app, and I cannot find a settings or whatever that allow me to redirect the domain.

Does anyone know how does it works? I would appreciated any kind of help...

Kind Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Go to  [Google Apps Page](http://www.google.com/a)
- Click Sign in (top right)
- Enter customer's *domain name*
- Change dropdown to *Domain Management*
- Click go
- Enter login details for *apps* administrator account.
- Click *Domain settings*
- Then click *Domain names*

I'm pretty sure you'll find your way from there. Shout if you're still stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Justhost is annoying coz they block port 465 and 567 which gmail uses to send mail.

This means his wordpress can only send mail via justhost and not his google apps email account. As a result when people receive an email from him it will show as from username@justhost.com and his customers will probably think it is a scam email.

When you see this problem go to just host help desk and make a complaint, hopefully if they get enough complaints from their customers they will open up port 465 for us and then we can use our gmail accounts as the SMTP server.